# How to convert Java method reference code to Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, java-8, android-livedata, method-reference

I've got this code in Java:

```
mViewModel.getSetupData().observe(this, this::updateTime);
```

The **updateTime** method accepts one parameter.
When converting this code to Kotlin, the following doesn't work:

```
mViewModel?.getSetupData()?.observe(this, ::updateTime)
```

The IDE (android studio) complains with a

> Type mismatch. Required: Observer. Found KFunction1.

Any clues?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: The syntax looks good. Try to build using gradle. Sometimes IDE restart helps to solve type inference problems.

Comment: The issue stems from the fact that this needs to be a Kotlin `val` androidx.lifecycle.Observer, not a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason Kotlin is not smart enough in providing `observe` overloads:

```
// Java declaration
public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<? super T> observer)
```

Now in Kotlin we have can call this method in two ways:

```
// Default Kotlin conversion [ #1 ]
fun observe(owner : LifecycleOwner, observer : Observer<in T>)

// SAM conversions [ #2 ]
fun observe(owner: () -> Lifecycle, observer : (T) -> Unit)
```

What we lack is something in-between, where we provide function only for observer argument.

If you already have dependency on Android KTX modules, namely `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx` (or at least `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx`) extension below should already be accessible. Otherwise you can quickly add it:

```
// custom extension with function observer argument [ #3 ]
@MainThread inline fun <T> LiveData<T>.observe(
    owner: LifecycleOwner,
    crossinline onChanged: (T) -> Unit
): Observer<T> {
    val wrappedObserver = Observer<T> { t -> onChanged.invoke(t) }
    observe(owner, wrappedObserver)
    return wrappedObserver
}
```

Now here's the difference in invocation:

```
// reusable observer object
val myObserver = Observer<TimeMeasurement> { updateTime(it) }

// function that updates time
fun updateTime(time : TimeMeasurement){
    // update views with time
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    /* ... */

    // default call [ #1 ]
    mViewModel.liveData.observe(this, myObserver)
    // default call but with object expression for observer [ #1 ]
    mViewModel.liveData.observe(this, Observer { updateTime(it) })
    // alternatively [ #1 ]
    mViewModel.liveData.observe(this, Observer(::updateTime))

    // SAM conversions, lets us pass function reference or a lambda [ #2 ]
    // in this case first argument is a lambda as well and it returns lifecycle
    mViewModel.liveData.observe({ lifecycle }, ::updateTime)

    // extension function call where we pass function reference as second argument [ #3 ]
    mViewModel.liveData.observe(this, ::updateTime)
    // or using lambda [ #3 ]
    mViewModel.liveData.observe(this) { updateTime(it) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the different examples.  What exactly is the `crossinline` in your code?

Comment: This is code snippet from Android KTX. `crossinline` is there to [prevent non-local returns](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns) from observer body.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can provide

```
.observe(this, Observer { someClass ->
    /*Here you can call your method*/
})
```

Yes, it's a little bit more verbose than java method, but for soe reason Kotlin can't infer type of lambda.

Comment: Thanks, and it still complains with **Type mismatch**.  Here is the signature of observe: 
`observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<? super T> observer) `
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observe(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20android.arch.lifecycle.Observer<T>)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody facing the same issue, this needs to be a Kotlin `val` from Android LiveData api.  It cannot be a function.  Here is the correct code of `updateTime` which works instead of the function:

```
    private val updateTime = Observer<TimeMeasurement> { 
      setupTimeMeasurement ->
      // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
      updateTimerData(setupTimeMeasurement, mViewModel!!.currentTimeValue)
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
    mViewModel?.getCountdownData()?.observe(this, updateTime)
```